# Receiving error message "name 'SaveInput' is not defined" while defining a save method Django

Tags: django, django-forms, cs50

I am trying to create a save method (.save()) for my forms.Form in Django views.py but I keep receiving an error message - name 'SaveInput' is not defined.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import forms
import markdown2

from . import util

class AddPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Tell us more!"
        })
    )


def add_page(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPageForm(request.POST)
        entries = util.list_entries()
        
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            saveInput = SaveInput(title=data['title'], content=data['content'])
            saveInput.save()
            
            for entry in entries:
                if title.upper() == entry.upper():
                    context = {
                        "title": title,
                        "content": content
                    }
                    return render(request, "encyclopedia/errorpage.html", context)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("/encyclopedia:index/?submitted=True"))
    else:
        return render (request, "encyclopedia/addpage.html", {
            "form": AddPageForm()
        })

    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\wiki\wiki\encyclopedia\views.py, line 84, in add_page
            saveInput = SaveInput(title=data['title'], content=data['content']) …
▶ Local vars
```

This is the part that I am trying to define a method and leading to the error message

```
            saveInput = SaveInput(title=data['title'], content=data['content'])
        saveInput.save()
```

Kindly tell me what I am doing wrong as the examples I have seen previously regarding the same save method did not require to define this.

Also, how do make sure that no page can be created if there is previously an added page with the same title without models .filter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either import or define `SaveInput` in your views.py

Comment: When you say I should import a SaveInput, please clarify because I thought that you only import previously defined method but this is a method that I am defining.                                            I got this solution from this stackoverflow suggestion                                                                                                                                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943912/how-do-you-write-a-save-method-for-forms-in-django

Comment: If you're defining a class, method, or function named SaveInput, can you include that code in your question?

Comment: I have updated the code to show the exact point that I am asking about. Thanks